# Storing html in Redis and keeping the quotes

Tags: python, redis

Is there a way to store a mix of quote characters as a value in Redis? My specific need is to store PHP and HTML strings, and keep the mix of quote types.

In Python:

```
import redis
db = redis.Redis('localhost')

phpfile = /root/test.php

with open(phpfile) as f:
    bar = f.read()

db.set('foo', bar)
```

If I try to pass the string any other direct way, it fails, of course, because of all the competing quotes.

**Edit:**

I'm going to close this question. I cannot get the behavior to repeat in Python using the code above, so it must be an issue with another layer in my code and not an issue with Redis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Redis does not care the structure of your data you store. You can throw random bytes at redis or strings with double or single quotes.

Simply store the string and be happy.

Comment: The problem is that Redis converts the quotes when I retrieve it. So, I'm getting (\"resources/foo.png\") back, which breaks the PHP.

Comment: Redis does not convert anything, at most it may be your redis library. Or your code for outputting.

Comment: @schroeder: maybe edit your question so it includes more of your code?